# How to combine an array of objects depending on the key: value of each object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have an array of json objects like below. Each object has permanent key 'type' and depending on the 'type', new keys are added.

So if `type: 'text'`, we have a new key 'text'.

If `type: 'notText'`, we have a new key 'attrs'.

```
arrayOfObj = [
    {
        "type": "text",
        "text": "="
    },
    {
        "type": "text",
        "text": " "
    },
    {
        "type": "text",
        "text": "S"
    },
    {
        "type": "text",
        "text": "O"
    },
    {
        "type": "notText",
        "attrs": {
            "id": 20,
            "data": "Something",
        }
    }
]
```

Depending on the 'type' of each item i.e. if type: 'text', then I need to combine each 'text' into 1 object like so:

```
arrayOfObj = [
    {
        "type": "text",
        "text": "= SO"
    },
    {
        "type": "notText",
        "attrs": {
            "id": 20,
            "data": "Something",
        }
    }
]
```

I know that to start it I can use

```
if(this.arrayOfObj.map(ed=>ed.type) === 'text') {
      Object.assign({}, ...arrayOfObj);           
}
```

However it doesn't quite work and I'm unsure of how to go further.

Would anyone have any idea of how to accomplish this?

Comment: What happens if for a given type you have a mix of `text` and `attr`? What should we do then?

Comment: There's only two values that 'type' could be, which is either 'text' or 'notText'. If it's 'text' then automatically a 'text' key will be included and if it's 'notText' then an 'attr' will be included. There won't be a obj with both 'text' and 'attr'. The issue isn't quite creating the keys it's more assigning values to the keys.

Comment: How to combine ```"type": "notText"``` object into one?

Comment: No it's more if 'type' = 'text', then combine the 'text' of all objects with 'type' = 'text', there's an example above with arrayOfObj. So starting with the first arrayOfObj, how to get to the second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Example below.**

```js
const arrayOfObj = [ { type: "text", text: "=", }, { type: "text", text: " ", }, { type: "text", text: "S", }, { type: "text", text: "O", }, { type: "notText", attrs: { id: 20, data: "Something", }, }, ];

const output = arrayOfObj.reduce(
  (a, b) => {
    if (b.type === "text") {
      a[0].text += b.text;
    } else {
      a.push({
        type: b.type,
        attrs: b.attrs,
      });
    }
    return a;
  },
  [{ type: "text", text: "" }]
);

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use reduce method to do this.

```js
arrayOfObj = [{
    "type": "text",
    "text": "="
  },
  {
    "type": "text",
    "text": " "
  },
  {
    "type": "text",
    "text": "S"
  },
  {
    "type": "text",
    "text": "O"
  },
  {
    "type": "notText",
    "attrs": {
      "id": 20,
      "data": "Something",
    }
  },
  {
    "type": "notText",
    "attrs": {
      "id": 22,
      "data": "Something",
    }
  }
]

const t = arrayOfObj.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  if (curr.type === "text") {
    const accTypeText = acc.find((v) => v.type === "text");
    if (accTypeText) {
      accTypeText.text += curr.text;
      return [...acc];
    }
  }
  return [...acc, curr];
}, [])

console.log(t);
```

Note: the map method return an array, so your if statement return always false

Answer (score 1):

We can use [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to create the desired object from the arrayOfObj input, if it is of type 'text' concatenate, otherwise just set the attrs.

```js
const arrayOfObj = [ { "type": "text", "text": "=" }, { "type": "text", "text": " " }, { "type": "text", "text": "S" }, { "type": "text", "text": "O" }, { "type": "notText", "attrs": { "id": 20, "data": "Something", } }, { "type": "someOtherType", "attrs": { "id": 35, "data": "Something else", } } ]
    
const result = Object.values(arrayOfObj.reduce((acc, { type, text, attrs }) => { 
    if (!acc[type]) acc[type] = { type };
    if (type === 'text') acc[type].text = (acc[type].text || '') + text;
    if (type !== 'text') acc[type].attrs = attrs;
    return acc;
}, {}));

console.log('Result:', result)
```

Answer (score 1):

I am breaking the problem step by step, I would do this:

```js
let arrayOfObj = [ { "type": "text", "text": "=" }, { "type": "text", "text": " " }, { "type": "text", "text": "S" }, { "type": "text", "text": "O" }, { "type": "notText", "attrs": { "id": 20, "data": "Something", } } ]
let completeString = "";

arrayOfObj.forEach(x => x.type == "text" ? completeString += x.text : "")
arrayOfObj = arrayOfObj.filter(x => x.type == "notText");
arrayOfObj.push({ "type": "text", "text": completeString })

console.log(arrayOfObj);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it. A similar idea to @[R3tep](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3083093/r3tep) &@[ikhvjs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14032355/ikhvjs)'s answers using `reduce`, only much less elegant.

```js
const arrayOfObj = [ { type: "text", text: "=", }, { type: "text", text: " ", }, { type: "text", text: "S", }, { type: "text", text: "O", }, { type: "notText", attrs: { id: 20, data: "Something", }, }, ];

function combineTexts(arrayOfObj) { 
    let noTextArray = arrayOfObj.filter(i => i.type !== 'text');
    let allTexts = arrayOfObj.filter(i => i.type === 'text')
                             .map(i => i.text)
                             .reduce((a, b) => a + b, '');
    noTextArray.unshift({ type: 'text', text: allTexts });
    return noTextArray;
}

console.log(combineTexts(arrayOfObj))
```